# Qt C++ | Программный осциллограф. Выбор виджета

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, виджет, графики

Стоит задача написания программного многоканального осциллографа. Данные от нескольких оцифрованных аналоговых и цифровых датчиков, передаваемые по Ethernet, должны выводится в нескольких областях построения с заданной группировкой графиков. Необходима обычная для осциллографов реализация синхронизации по триггеру, масштабирование по времени, наличие вертикальных курсоров.

В качестве программного фреймворка выбран Qt (C++). На начальном этапе озадачился выбором библиотеки подходящих для этой цели виджетов. Погуглив на эту тему и пообщавшись с коллегами, пришел к выводу, что есть три варианта:

- Qwt,
- QCustomPlot,
- QOpenGLWidget.

С последним есть опыт работы, но для видео потокового видео. А в поставленной задаче с ним, как я понимаю, придется все тонкости работы с графиками самому реализовывать.

С Qwt и QCustomPlot не работал. Знаю, что именно их чаще всего рекомендуют и они в настоящее время достаточно конкурентны между собой. Потому и прошу совета более опытных и знающих специалистов, какое решение выбрать для своей задачи? Так, чтобы и вывод графиков не был тормознутым, и все указанные фичи осциллографа можно было бы реализовать.

Comment: Все зависит от того, сколько точек одновременно будете выводить на графиках. С `QCustomPlot` работать проще, но `Qwt` работает быстрее. Если выводить в пределах нескольких сотен точек - то QCustomPlot справится со своей задачей и тормозить не будет.

Answer (score 2):

`QCustomPlot` - это 2 файла, .cpp и .h, которые вы включаете в проект, можете редактировать, практически мгновенно пересобирать, использовать с равным успехом под Linux и Windows. Хорошо документирован и имеет множество примеров использования. Из недостатков - если загрузить 100000 точек и более, то получите серьезное подтормаживание. Имеет ограничения в использовании по лицензии - бесплатно для свободных проектов и платно для коммерческих проектов.

`Qwt` - быстро работает, [внедряется в `QtCreator`](https://russianblogs.com/article/54451129260/), хорошо документирован, имеет множество готовых шаблонов. Так же может быть использован под Win и Linux. Недостаток - это огромный монстр, которого нужно пересобирать под различные ABI, соответственно, сложно редактировать.
Интересно услышать и другие мнения, т.к. тоже интересуюсь этим вопросом, и однозначного ответа нет.