# Наилучшая библиотека для отрисовки графиков в Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, поиск-библиотек

В интернете при поиске по аналогичным запросам выпадают ссылки 10+ летней давности, где люди в основном пишут что QCustomPlot является более лучшей альтернативой чем QCharts и Qwt. Хотелось бы узнать положение дел на текущий момент времени, Qcp всё также является лучшим выбором или мб есть смысл присмотреться к другим библиотекам?

Comment: QCustomPlot - GPL, а Qwt - облегченная LGPL, так что трудно сравнивать если проект не открытый

Comment: QCharts - это вообще для студентов поделка.

Comment: Qwt более многофункциональная вещь (там ещё есть QwtPolar), но всей этой глубиной не сильно пользуются из-за слабой документации

Comment: С чего бы это вдруг QCP - лучший выбор? Только в том, что его проще подключать к проекту и легче освоить. Qwt меньше тормозит на большом числе точек.
Похожий вопрос и ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1465170/qt-c-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0/1465591#1465591

Comment: @eugesh, да кстати, я обычно делаю такой тест, сую синус из миллиона точек и смотрю как быстро это работает

Comment: Ну и Qwt порвет QCP на таком тесте

Comment: Вы серьёзно хотите, чтоб кто-то за Вас сравнил библиотеки в абсолютном зачёте?